# es6 のreturn

Tags: javascript, es6

```
 module.exports = {
     add : (value1, value2) =>
     return value1 + value2
 }
```

このように書いたところエラーになりましたが原因がわかりません。

return を消したら通りましたが、なぜreturnがあるとだめなのかがわかっていません。

Answer (score 7):

ref: [アロー関数 | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax)

arrow関数のstatements部分にreturnを用いる場合は`{}`で囲む必要がありそうです。

```js
module.exports = {
    add : (value1, value2) => {return value1 + value2}
}
```

また、returnを省略して以下のようにも書けますね。

```js
module.exports = {
    add : (value1, value2) => value1 + value2
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`{}` を省略できるのは、書きたいコードが単一の「式」の場合だけです。代入文の右辺や関数のパラメータになれるのが式です。

`return` を含め、「文」を書きたい場合は `{}`を書く必要があります。

なぜこのような仕様になっているのかですが、[TC39 Wiki](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/)を読むと単にC#のラムダ式の文法を真似たのではと思えます(はっきりとは書いていません)。